# Form submission opens php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form on html page. it has action as `mailer.php`. All code works properly, but on submission, page goes to mailer.php and browser shows an empty page on screen

contactus.html form tag:

```
<form id="form_20" action="mailer.php" method="post" target="_self" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //input fields here
</form>
```

mailer.php file:

```
<?php
$to = '---------------'; //Removed for privacy
$subject = 'New Enquiry';

$name = $_POST['Name'];
$tel = $_POST['Number'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$comments = $_POST['Message'];

$body = "From: $name \nNumber: $tel \nEmail id: $email \nComments: $comments";
$headers = 'FROM: ---------------------------'.PHP_EOL; //Removed for privacy
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<script>alert("Your data has been submitted.");</script>';
?>
```

The code works fine, I get the mail too.
The only problem I have is that the page redirects to mailer.php

P.S. : If anyone finds this a duplicate question, please comment the link to the question it duplicates so I get my answer. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the `target="_self"` attribute?

Comment: It has to go to `mailer.php` for the PHP to process. Alternatively you could process the form data via ajax. You don't get the alerted message currently?

Comment: well you tell it to go to mailer.php - so no surprise. what do you want to happen?

Comment: I get the alerted message, but on clicking ok, I am redirected to mailer.php, which is a blank page @chris85

Comment: Let me try it @AdamJeffers

Comment: No you are redirected from the form because you tell it to; the alert is after that while on the mailer page. You can use `header` to redirect it after, take out the echo `script`.

Comment: See chris85's comment... and Dragon's answer...

Comment: You could make the form submit to the same page by removing the `action=""`.

Comment: I've done this same thing once before for form submission that I'm doing right now, and what bugs me is that last time no such problem occured on using this same code on another page,
But this time I'm redirected to my php page

Comment: simply not possible. the form code sends the browser to the url in action.

Comment: I don't know how, but it has happened,
Check www.visioncargoservices.com/contactus.html form, NO redirection, with the same code I'm using right now.

Comment: why cant you just look at the code then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to send the user back to the previous page:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/foo.php?back=yes'); //add your url
```

after the mail call, and remove the script

on foo.php

```
if ($_GET['back']=='yes'){
echo '<script>alert("Your data has been submitted.");</script>';
}
```

Comment: Maybe `exit(header());`?

Comment: as the file ended after mail, i was happy to leave exit out this time

Comment: If I use this, I dont get the alert box

Comment: @telekineser is error reporting enabled? If not an error could be happening earlier on in the script which is preventing execution of the rest of the code. If you are on localhost make sure that you have setup php.ini so you can send emails.

Comment: @telekineser added a solution for that